# Partitions: data overrite risc

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery

So my question is simple: You have only one HDD and 2 partitions; can writing data on one partition overwrite the data on the other partition so you cant recover the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, because the data stored on a partition can't interfere with another partition's data.
And that's why you can format a partition without touching the other partitions.

(But you can mess partitions if you have low-level access and/or a tool for it. But this is not the case ;) )